# laravel 5.6.4 authentication with "tymon/jwt-auth" is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, jwt

I was trying to install tymon/jwt-auth with laravel 5.6.4 using composer

composer require tymon/jwt-auth

but it is showing some error like this:

```
Using version ^0.5.12 for tymon/jwt-auth
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.6
- Conclusion: don't install barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.5
- Conclusion: don't install barryvdh/laravel-cors V0.8.4
- Conclusion: don't install barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.3
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.6.3
- Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-cors ^0.8.2 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-cors[V0.8.4, v0.8.2, v0.8.3, v0.8.5, v0.8.6].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.8.2 requires illuminate/support 5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4].
- don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.6.3, required as 5.6.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.3].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

**Update:**

Firstly I was trying `composer update` command adding some specific version of dependencies in composer.json file. Like `"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"` and `"barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.8.2"`.

After that I was trying `composer require tymon/jwt-auth` not removing the lines with specific version of `tymon/jwt-auth` and `barryvdh/laravel-cors`.
 After removing the lines from composer.json file with specific versions of `tymon/jwt-auth` the

```
composer require tymon/jwt-auth
```

command is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The package [tymon/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) doesn't offer a stable version for use with Laravel 5.6 just yet, that's why composer can't resolve the dependency requirements.

If you check [their releases](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/releases) they do have an RC (Release Candidate) available with support for Laravel 5.5 and 5.6. The one you would be interested in should be `1.0.0-rc.2`.