# Cannot update dependencies with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, jwt, guzzle, laravel-socialite

I am trying to install the package tymon/jwt-auth via composer on production server and I am getting errors while resolving dependencies.

I have installed it succesfully on my local vagrant environment but when on production server the following output.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/socialite 3.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.2.x-dev|install laravel/socialite 3.0.x-dev
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev].
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.1 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.x-dev].
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.2 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.x-dev].
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.3 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.x-dev].
    - laravel/socialite v2.0.4 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~4.0|~5.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.0, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.1, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.2, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.3, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[5.3.x-dev, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.x-dev, 6.2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 6.2.x-dev, required as ~5.3|~6.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/socialite 3.0.x-dev|install laravel/socialite v2.0.0|install laravel/socialite v2.0.1|install laravel/socialite v2.0.2|install laravel/socialite v2.0.3|install laravel/socialite v2.0.4
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[2.0.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.10, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.11, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.12, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.13, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.14, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.15, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.16, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.17, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.18, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.19, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.20, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.21, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.22, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.5, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.6, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.7, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.8, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/socialite[v2.0.9, 3.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite (locked at 3.0.x-dev, required as ^2.0@dev) -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[3.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[2.0.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.2, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9].
```

I've tried both on the server by running composer update and by doing composer require tymon/jwt-auth.

How can start resolving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/cholung/laravel-model-builder.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/vorodevops/l5scaffold.git"
        },
        {
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "https://github.com/alnutile/l5scaffold.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^3.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0@dev",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1@dev",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "~3.0",
        "xinax/laravel-gettext": "3.x",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "moltin/laravel-cart": "^5.0",
        "jenssegers/date": "^3.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.3",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
        "wisembly/elephant.io": "^3.1",
        "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^6.0",
        "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "jimbolino/laravel-model-builder" : "dev-master",
        "laralib/l5scaffold": "dev-viewonly",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Artvisual\\Tools\\": "packages/artvisual/tools/src",
            "Artvisual\\Tools\\Providers\\": "packages/artvisual/tools/src/Providers",
            "Artvisual\\Payment\\": "packages/artvisual/payment/src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/48888004/10281918 ?

Comment: Is there a special reason you do not update the `composer.lock` file locally and then only run `composer install` to prepare your production environment?

Comment: @xabbuh Since I have taken over the entire project, I realised that the crew that was developing it was only pushing the `composer.json`, not the `composer.lock`. In fact, the `composer.lock` looks very very different in local and in server. I am afraid that if I push the `composer.lock` from my local enviornment and do a `composer install` some thinks will start to not working, and this project is very big to start making so big changes. In fact, all `composer update` commands that I made on the server, were made with the `--dry-run` flag, just for knowing what is going to happen.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I did, but that does not work for me. Thanks in any case.

Comment: then bring the composer.lock from your prod environment back to dev and push it to the code repository. unfortunately you need to start over on your dev environment then, but that is the only save way. if you do not use a composer.lock the projects is going to break sooner or later on prod

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still needs a solution to this. In this [guide](https://discuss.flarum.org/d/24684-can-only-install-one-of-guzzlehttpguzzle) it says that you should

1. `composer require` the older version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle`, like for example `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^5.3.0`
2. `composer require` the package you were looking out to install in the first place, like for example `composer require laravel/socialite`
3. `composer remove` the `guzzlehttp/guzzle` dependency again with `composer remove guzzlehttp/guzzle`

I got this error when requiring the `jonasva/google-trends` dependency and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue and the guzzle version was 7.0.
I have solved it by changing the version to 6.0 in composer.json and updated it.